# ORACLE APEX PL/SQL Process not responding when called with AJAX during onbeforepageunload

Tags: javascript, ajax, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX 4.2. I built a PLSQL process that is set to execute "On Demand - When this process is called by AJAX". This process is designed to update two member attributes in a collection that I created when the page loaded. Its code follows:

```
DECLARE
v_seq_id NUMBER;
BEGIN

--get sequence id
SELECT seq_id into v_seq_id FROM apex_collections 
WHERE collection_name = 'THE_COLLECTION' and c001 = :APP_SESSION;

--I've tried uncommenting this script to see if this works, too
--htp.script('alert(''PLSQL Process works'');');

--update first member attribute    
apex_collection.update_member_attribute(
p_collection_name =>'THE_COLLECTION',
p_seq => v_seq_id,
p_attr_number => 2, 
p_attr_value => 0);


--update second member attribute
apex_collection.update_member_attribute(
p_collection_name =>'THE_COLLECTION',
p_seq => v_seq_id,
p_attr_number => 3, 
p_attr_value => sysdate);

END;
```

When I try calling this process with AJAX/javascript before the page unloads, nothing happens. I placed this code in the "Execute on Page Load" portion of my page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
//this alert box works, so I know the function is called
alert('Unloading...');
//call the PLSQL process 
 var get = new htmldb_Get(null,$v('pFlowId'), 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=THE_PROCESS',1234);         
get.get();
//this also works, so I know the function completes
 alert('end');
};
```

I test this two ways. First, I have some logic built into my page that depends on whether or not these member attributes were updated. When I reload the page, it behaves as if the PLSQL process never ran. Second, I have tried uncommenting the htp.script line in the PLSQL code above, but it will not execute either.

When I try running the following in my browser's F12 tools, the console prints "alert('test');" without actually displaying an error message:

```
var get = new htmldb_Get(null,$v('pFlowId'), 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=THE_PROCESS',1234);         
get.get();
```

I've also tried running it with window.onload, but that doesn't seem to work either.

When I run the PLSQL process as an "After Header" process, the htp.script code launches an alert box successfully, and the process seems to work.

Does anyone know how to get this to work with AJAX? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: First off I'd like to mention you shouldn't really be using htmldb_Get anymore. It's been undocumented since forever and there are better options for it. However, I think it should work, in a way. You really need to open up your network tab in your browser's dev tools (network in chrome, console or network in FF) and check calls to wwv_flow.show. Furthermore, returning the script code with htp.p for an ajax call will not automatically show an alert.

Comment: Another remark: what is it you're trying to do? Because you have to realize the beforeunload won't catch all situations where a user "leaves". Session times out for example? No entry. Browser crash? No entry.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've never used the network tab before, but when I used it to examine wwv_flow.show, I found that the htp.script actually was being returned by the process. It just wasn't displaying the alert box, as you said. It turns out that it was actually a problem with the process itself not updating my collection properly.

Comment: That is fine that no entries are made for session timeouts and browser crashes. I'm using this to "check out" a page. It's a long story, but I'm basically trying to prevent the users from opening up multiple tabs of a specific page. If the collection value shows that a page is checked out by a specific Session ID, then the user will not be allowed to open the tab until it is checked back in. Since the collection value is tied to the session ID (which is reset whenever they log into the page again), it doesn't matter if the process doesn't run when the user is forced to log out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was in the PLSQL process, after all. Following the suggestion from Tom's comment, I looked at wwv_flow.show in the network tab of my browser's development tools. When I viewed the "Response body" tab under "detailed view", I found that the process was returning the results of the htp.script command; it just wasn't generating the alert box itself.

After a bit of troubleshooting, I figured out that the following code in my PLSQL process was not working:

```
--update first member attribute    
apex_collection.update_member_attribute(
p_collection_name =>'THE_COLLECTION',
p_seq => v_seq_id,
p_attr_number => 2, 
p_attr_value => 0);
```

I changed it to :

```
UPDATE apex_collections SET n001 = 0 WHERE c001 = :APP_SESSION and collection_name = 'THE_COLLECTION';
```

In order to make this work, I had to execute a command to grant the update permission to my database user:

```
GRANT UPDATE ON apex_collections TO USER
```